# error C3861: 'strtoll': identifier not found

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, strtol

The main problem I am facing here is that `strtoll()` is flagged as an error in VC 2010 (`error C3861: 'strtoll': identifier not found`). Will it do the same thing if I replace it with `strtol()`?

```
unsigned int get_uintval_from_arg(int argc, int index, char **argv,
                                  unsigned int lower_bound, unsigned int upper_bound) 
{  
    unsigned int return_val=0;

    if (index + 1 <= argc - 1)
    {
        return_val=(unsigned int)strtoll(argv[index+1],NULL,10);
        if (errno == EINVAL || errno== ERANGE) 
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not parse argument %s for switch %s!\n",
                    argv[index], argv[index+1]);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    // ....... I will post the remaining part of the code if necessary 
    .......
}
```

Comment: Did you `#include <stdlib.h>` in your program? Since a `long long` is so much longer than an `unsigned long`, why are you trying to use the `long long` variant?

Comment: `long long` is part of the latest ISO 9899:99 C standard, "C99", which is not supported by Microsoft. Visual Studio only supports the twenty-one years old C standard from 1990.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your `return_val` is an `unsigned int`, you should probably be using `strtoul()` which has been standard since C89 and is therefore supported by MSVC (whereas `strtoll()` has only been standard since C99 and is not supported by MSVC).

Your testing of the error conditions is not adequate.  You need to set `errno` to zero before calling the conversion function; you also need to detect whether an error was reported, which is trickier than it seems.

Section §7.20.1.4 'The strtol, strtoll, strtoul, and strtoull functions' of the C99 standard says:

> **Returns**
>
> The `strtol`, `strtoll`, `strtoul`, and `strtoull` functions return the converted
>   value, if any. If no conversion could be performed, zero is returned. If the correct value
>   is outside the range of representable values, LONG_MIN, LONG_MAX, LLONG_MIN,
>   LLONG_MAX, ULONG_MAX, or ULLONG_MAX is returned (according to the return type
>   and sign of the value, if any), and the value of the macro ERANGE is stored in `errno`.

You also have to read the look at the value stored in the `endptr` parameter to the conversion functions to tell that no conversion was performed (as opposed to a valid zero was converted).

> If the subject sequence is empty or does not have the expected form, no conversion is
>   performed; the value of `nptr` is stored in the object pointed to by `endptr`, provided
>   that `endptr` is not a null pointer.

So, you must write code more like this (omitting the test against EINVAL because the standard does not mention these functions setting `errno` to EINVAL):

```
unsigned int return_val=0;

if (index + 1 <= argc - 1)
{
    char *end;
    unsigned long ul;
    errno = 0;
    ul = strtoul(argv[index+1], &end, 10);
    if ((ul == 0 && end == argv[index+1]) ||
        (ul == ULONG_MAX && errno == ERANGE) ||
        (ul > UINT_MAX))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not parse argument %s for switch %s!\n",
                argv[index], argv[index+1]);
        return 0;
    }
    retval = (unsigned int)ul;
}
```

Note that this is simpler than the test for a signed integer conversion which must take into account the negative `<type>_MIN` limit as well as the `<type>_MAX` limit.

Also note that you really should record the result in an `unsigned long` and then check whether it fits within your designated range, which may be limited to UINT_MAX (which can be less than ULONG_MAX in a Unix-like 64-bit environment).

Comment: also, you should check for `retval > UINT_MAX` as well (before downcasting to `unsigned int`), in case it's on a 64-bit long platform.

Comment: @bdonlan: yes - thanks (to both comments).  I fixed the downcast with the last paragraph without seeing your comment (but the first edition of the answer didn't include that, and your comment is spot on). I had missed my '=' instead of '==' typo (but the compiler would have warned me about it had I compiled the code).

Comment: You've fixed the downcast but left in the ul > UINT_MAX test which will now always be false.

Comment: @DavidConrad: why do you think that test will always be false? On a 64-bit (Unix) machine, it is trivial to have an `unsigned long` value that is much larger than will fit in `unsigned int`. On Windows 64 or a 32-bit system, you're correct; however, I believe the code will work correctly on those too — though a compiler might decide to warn about the test.  If that was a problem, I'd arrange for conditional compilation, probably look for `ULONG_MAX != UINT_MAX` and only making the comparision if the two are different.

Comment: Whoops! Sorry, I was thinking ULONG_MAX, not UINT_MAX. My mistake.

Answer (score 4):

In Visual studio use `_strtoi64()` method instead. It has the same parameters as `strtoll`.

For compatibility you can simply use a define to wrap it as strtoll (if you need portability) such as

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER)
#define strtoll _strtoi64
#endif
```

Comment: @PaulR Yeah he said specifically VS though. If he wants it to be portable he should use defines to redefine _strtoi64 as strtoll on microsoft c compiler.

Comment: @bdonlan Yeah I noticed afterwards since i had issues porting some code to VS C compiler before I kind of ignored what he was doing and just told him why strtoll wasn't working.

Comment: @JesusRamos, see my comment on wallyk's post - there is a reason for it actually

Answer (score 0):

`strtol()` is the proper library function for a `long`.  For portability, declare `return_val` as a long or `unsigned long`.  If the latter, see if MSVC offers `strtoul()`.

Comment: Yeah he's using stroll for long long int, but casts down to unsigned int... I kind of skipped over that heh.

Comment: If `long` and `int` are the same size, this is a reasonable way to parse values between `INT_MAX+1..UINT_MAX`.

Comment: @bdonlan:  assuming `long` and `int` are the same size is short-sighted.  It is quite simple and easy to write it portably: that should be emphasized, not taking an environment-sensitive lazy shortcut, which will easily cost significant time when it eventually breaks.

Comment: i have tried it with strol() and it works, but I am not sure if it can do the same thing as stroll()

Comment: @wallyk, it's not quite that easy, actually - using it directly gives wrong answers for values greater than `LONG_MAX` (clamped to `LONG_MAX`; see http://codepad.org/nu9L2AED); and all this code assumes is that `long long` is larger than `int`; it DOES NOT make the assumption that `long == int`.

Comment: @bdonlan:  I amended my answer a few minutes before your comment to mention `strtoul` which addresses the `LONG_MAX` issue.  Downcasting a `long long` to a `long` in `C` will toss the most significant bits.  To be completely proper, a check should be made instead of truncating.

Answer (score 0):

For your purposes, you should use [strtoul](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5k9xb7x1%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), as you are converting to an `unsigned long` type, not a `signed long long` type (which is what `strtoll` would do). If you need to read in `long long`s, use the Microsoft-specific [_strtoi64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h80404d3%28VS.80%29.aspx); you can use `#define`s to rename it to `strtoll` on Microsoft platforms, or write a wrapper function in a Windows-specific portability shims file (with your own prototype for it in a private header).