# Command line argument integer error checking in C

Tags: c, parsing, error-handling, integer

I'm trying to successfully parse an integer from the arguments given on a command line for C. The given input will look something like this:

> a.out 2

Very simple.  However I cannot figure out how to have error checking on this.  For example each of the following runs should throw an error:

> a.out 2hi
>
> a.out 9hello
>
> a.out 4x

The error handling I have implemented catches any non-integer characters in front of the integer itself (e.g. "> a.out hi4") as I am using sscanf.  Atoi() and strtol() don't work because they just parse the integer value off the front of the argument.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just loop over your argument and bellow if you encounter a non-digit then. What more could you ask for? BTW: `scanf()` allows whitespace before the number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `strtol()` and check that the end of what it converted is the end of the string:

```
char *end;

errno = 0;
long l = strtol(argv[1], &end, 10);  // 0 if you want octal/hex/decimal

if (end == argv[i] || *end != '\0' || ((l == LONG_MIN || l == LONG_MAX) && errno == ERANGE))
    …report problems…
…either use l as a long, or check that it is in the range INT_MIN..INT_MAX
```

This will skip quietly over leading blanks.  If that's a problem, you can check for them too:

```
if (!isdigit((unsigned char)argv[i]) && argv[i] != '+' && argv[i] != '-')
   …first character isn't part of a decimal number…
```

See also:

- [What is wrong with the following C code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8239013/what-is-wrong-with-the-following-c-code/8239178#8239178)
- [Correct usage of `strtol()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14176123/correct-usage-of-strtol/14176593#14176593).

Answer (score 0):

```
int is_integer(char *str)
{   
    if(!str)
        return 0;
    int len = 0, pmflag = 0;
    while(*str != '\0') // if you sure about null-termination
    {
        if(*str == '-' || *str == '+')
        {
            if(len)
                return 0;
            pmflag = 1;
        }
        else if(*str < '0' || *str > '9')
        {
            return 0;
        }
        len++;
        str++;
    }
    if(pmflag && len == 1)
        return 0;
    return 1;
}
```